# Display props of a component in a table format Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component called 'tabs' with some props that I want to display in a table on another page.

```
export default {
  name: 'tabs',
  props: {
    id: {
      type: [String, Number],
    },
    class: {
      type: String,
      default: 'tab-links',
    },
  },
}
```

I have imported the tabs component to another page and I would like to show the props that are being used by this component on the page like a styleguide.
This is how I would like the props to be displayed

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Default value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>String or Number</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>'tab-links'</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

How can I go about doing this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If your components pages are in the same level so you can do it easily with $emit event:
Page1:

```
created(){
this.$emit('emitName',propToSend)
}
```

Page2:
Will get the 'propToSend' as a prop like perents & children